# Error after Ubuntu upgrade from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, upgrade

I have recently upgraded my laptop from ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS. The upgrade procedure seemed successful. But the restart after the upgrade was not successful and now I am getting the below error as shown in the screen shot while booting. [error screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3Mb8.jpg)

How to rectify it ? or else how to revert back to 16.04 LTS.

Thanks,
Dibash

Comment: Your screenshot shows that disk errors were detected and repaired during the boot process, however, your question is not clear on where the boot process stops.

Comment: Hi Kristopher, the boot process stops when the ubuntu logo appears and the screen gets frozen and the error as in the screen shot appears automatically.